# Changing UIStoryboards Based On Device Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I started off with an iPhone only app that had iPhone 4 sized screen support and I wanted to convert it to a universal app that also worked on iPads so I created a new storyboard named "Storyboard-iPad" and put the following code into my AppDelegate.m. This did not work as when i launch the app it still works on the iPhone 5 & 4 sized screens but when i run it on an iPad simulator it just stays as the iPhone 5 version in the top left hand corner. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong and what i need to do to fix this error?

Any help is very much appreciated,

Thanks!

AppDelegate.m

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
   UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 960){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard-iPhone4" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }

    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard-iPad"

                                                   bundle: nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ate trying to write code to do something iOS will do automatically.

Rename your iPhone storyboard `Storyboard~iphone`.  Rename your iPad storyboard `Storyboard~ipad`.  Set your main interface name to `Storyboard` in your application target's settings.

If you use these names, with tildes and lower-case device strings, the resource loader will automatically select the appropriate resource for the current device.

This is documented in [the *Bundle Programming Guide*: “Device-Specific Resources in iOS”](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW16).

Comment: Yes but then what do i name my iPhone 4 storyboard?